Implementing streaming rendering
So I recently watched this video where they show how streaming rendering is implemented. So I copied what they did:
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var app = builder.Build();

            app.MapGet("/streaming", async (HttpResponse response) =>
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {
                    await response.WriteAsync($"<p>Hello {i}</p>\n");
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                }
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }

but to my surprise when I browse to '/streaming' the browser doesn't stream the response. Instead it spins for 3 seconds showing a blank page and then shows the response in it's entirety at the very end.
Why did it work in the video and why doesn't it work in my browser, is it perhaps because of a browser setting?
